# Writing an random access iterator over parallel arrays

Tags: c++, boost, refactoring, c++11, boost-iterators

**Background**
Large application with a bundle of code, I can't change the storage mechanism.

I would like to create an iterator over a set of multi-dimensional data stored in parallel arrays so we can start using std algorithms & containers.

Any ideas on how to make this work correctly?

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class curve_point_iterator;

const int curve_size = 10;

class curve
{
public:
  curve()
  {
    std::fill( x, &x[curve_size], 0.0 );
    std::fill( y, &y[curve_size], 0.0 );
  }

  double x[curve_size];
  double y[curve_size];

  curve_point_iterator begin();
  curve_point_iterator end();
};

class point_reference
{
public:
  point_reference( double& x_, double& y_ )
    : x( x_ )
    , y( y_ )
  {
  }

  point_reference& operator = ( point_reference& other )
  {
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;

    return *this;
  }

  double & x;
  double & y;
};

class curve_point_iterator 
  : public boost::iterator_facade< 
          curve_point_iterator
        , point_reference
        , boost::random_access_traversal_tag >
{
public:
  curve_point_iterator()
    : index(0)
    , curve_(nullptr)
  {}

  explicit curve_point_iterator( curve* curve_in, size_t index_ = 0 )
    : index( index_ )
    , curve_( curve_in )
  {}

private:
  friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

  void increment()
  {
    ++index;
  }

  void decrement()
  {
    --index;
  }

  void advance( size_t n )
  {
    index += n;
  }

  difference_type distance_to( curve_point_iterator const& other ) const
  {
    return other.index - this->index;
  }

  bool equal(curve_point_iterator const& other) const
  {
      return this->index == other.index && this->curve_ == other.curve_;
  }

  point_reference& dereference() const
  {
    auto pt_ref = new( point_reference_buffer ) point_reference(  curve_->x[index]
                                                                , curve_->y[index] );
    return *pt_ref;
  }

  size_t index;
  mutable char point_reference_buffer[sizeof(point_reference)];
  curve* curve_;
};


curve_point_iterator curve::begin()
{
  return curve_point_iterator( this );
}

curve_point_iterator curve::end()
{
  return curve_point_iterator( this, curve_size+1 );
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  curve crv;

  crv.x[1] = 20;
  crv.x[2] = 10;

  std::sort( crv.begin(), crv.end(), []( point_reference const& a, point_reference const& b )
  {
    return a.x < b.x;
  });

  for( auto i = 0; i < curve_size; ++i )
  {
    std::cout << crv.x[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**
    0
    20
    20
    20
    20
    20
    20
    20
    20
    20

After changing to

```
class point_reference
{
  ... ( all the other stuff )
  double x; // no longer reference
  double y; // no longer reference
};
```

**Output**
    0
    20
    10
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0

Comment: It's not possible to assign the x and y references in point_reference::operator=. I'm not entirely sure how that even compiles? I'm guessing that operator= doesn't even get called and the default generated copy constructor is assigning x and y.

Comment: Its just copying the values, not changing the reference.  I guess I don't even need the operator =, its left over from when I boiled this down into some simpler code.

Comment: I'm using the placement new operator to change the reference.

Comment: BTW your `curve` constructor could be much more succinctly written as `curve () : x(), y() { }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what you need to do is to introduce a point type (which has value semantics) in addition to point_reference, which has the reference semantics you're looking for.  You need the value semantics so that operations such as swap act as the standard expects.  You can use the fourth argument of `iterator_facade` to allow this.  Also, this way there is no need to use that mutable buffer, since the point_reference itself is returned by value.

Also, your `curve::end()` used the wrong index, and should use `curve_size` as its index.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class curve_point_iterator;

const int curve_size = 10;

class curve
{
public:
  curve()
  {
    std::fill( x, &x[curve_size], 0.0 );
    std::fill( y, &y[curve_size], 0.0 );
  }

  double x[curve_size];
  double y[curve_size];

  curve_point_iterator begin();
  curve_point_iterator end();
};

class point
{
public:
  point( const double& x_, const double& y_ )
    : x( x_ )
    , y( y_ )
  {
  }

  double x;
  double y;
};


class point_reference
{
public:
  point_reference( double& x_, double& y_ )
    : x( x_ ),
      y( y_ )
  {
  }

  point_reference& operator = ( const point& other )
  {
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;

    return *this;
  }

  operator point() const
  {
    return point(x, y);
  }

  double & x;
  double & y;

  point_reference& operator=(const point_reference& other)
  {
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
  }

  point_reference* operator->()
  {
     return this;
  }

  point_reference* operator->() const
  {
     return this;
  }


};

class curve_point_iterator 
  : public boost::iterator_facade< 
          curve_point_iterator
  , point
  , boost::random_access_traversal_tag
  , point_reference>
{
public:
  curve_point_iterator()
    : index(0)
    , curve_(nullptr)
  {}

  explicit curve_point_iterator( curve* curve_in, size_t index_ = 0 )
    : index( index_ )
    , curve_( curve_in )
  {}

  point_reference operator->() const
  {
     return dereference();
  }

private:
  friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

  void increment()
  {
    ++index;
  }

  void decrement()
  {
    --index;
  }

  void advance( size_t n )
  {
    index += n;
  }

  difference_type distance_to( curve_point_iterator const& other ) const
  {
    return other.index - this->index;
  }

  bool equal(curve_point_iterator const& other) const
  {
    return this->index == other.index && this->curve_ == other.curve_;
  }

  point_reference dereference() const
  {
    //    auto pt_ref = new( point_reference_buffer ) point_reference(  curve_->x[index]
    //                                , curve_->y[index] );
    //    return *pt_ref;
    return point_reference(curve_->x[index], curve_->y[index]);
  }

  size_t index;
  curve* curve_;
};


curve_point_iterator curve::begin()
{
  return curve_point_iterator( this );
}

curve_point_iterator curve::end()
{
  return curve_point_iterator( this, curve_size );
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  curve crv;

  crv.x[1] = 20;
  crv.x[2] = 10;

  std::sort( crv.begin(), crv.end(), []( point const& a, point const& b )
         {
           return a.x < b.x;
         });

  for( auto i = 0; i < curve_size; ++i )
    {
      std::cout << crv.x[i] << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
10
20
```

Comment: I had tried this but ran into a bug with my unit tests.  Anytime the operator-> is called on the iterator it spits a compiler error, so I didn't see that it was the correctish path.

Comment: @Zac Okay, according to the boost::iterator_facade docs, if you need to use a non-reference as the reference return, you'll also need to provide an operator->() that returns a proxy.  I then added the operator->() to the proxy that lets it behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have build a proxy, apparently its supposed to build the proxy if needed.  I've got it worked out at the moment. Also see boost bug [#5697](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5697)